# How to click on a <Td> element

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I want to click *AutoTestSKU* of the table below. How do I do it using selenium Java?

```
<tr class="poslist-item" onclick="callManage(this, 'a[id$=linkManageProduct]')">
<tr class="poslist-item" onclick="callManage(this, 'a[id$=linkManageProduct]')">
<tr class="poslist-item" onclick="callManage(this, 'a[id$=linkManageProduct]')">
   <td>
      <input id="listProductform:productItemRepeat:2:checkbox" class="toggle-checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" value="true" name="listProductform:productItemRepeat:2:checkbox">
   </td>
   <td> Cash Withdraw </td>
   <td>AutoTestSKU</td>
   <td>AutoProductName</td>
   <td> 1 </td>
   <td> 999 </td>
   <td> 0 </td>
   <td> 0 </td>
   <td>
   <td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid row-break">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go with `xpath` text based search. I also found element load issue is very common with `webtables` so make sure to use `explicit` wait as needed. See [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) for implementation.

```
//td[.='AutoTestSKU']
```

`.` gives you the ability to directly point to the parent in `html` hierarchy

If the text contains any whitespace it will not work. In that case you can use xpath `contains()` function.

```
//td[contains(text(),'AutoTestSKU')]


WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'AutoTestSKU')]")));
myDynamicElement.click();
```